# "Save as ..." in Microsoft Office always brings up "Documents" folder in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, ms-office, office-365

"Save as ..." ignores the location of the current file and ignores the last save location. This means I have to navigate back to the original files source folder every time I want to save a different version of the file in Excel.

[image]

Comment: Documents by default go into the Documents directory. Use numbers, you wont have this issue, mS aren't oriented around Ease of use as much as Apple .

Comment: What do you mean by use numbers?

Comment: Sorry, try in Apple's Numbers App.

Answer (score 1):

Many apps do this. Years ago a utility was released called [DefaultFolderX](http://www.defaultfolder.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html). It lets you fix this problem for all apps, and it can even store two different locations- one for opening files, one for saving files. It’s excellent for when you open files from one directory, work on them and save them into another directory.

It is unlikely that Microsoft will do anything about this function as they would regard it as the operating system’s responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a complaint than a question. Or a feature request. You can log feature requests for Office 365 on Microsoft's [Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback).

There are separate feedback sections for the individual Office applications i.e. OneDrive, OneNote, Teams and so on.

Make a feature request. People vote for it. Microsoft uses these votes to prioritize which features to implement.

Comment: It's only a complaint if the feature doesn't exist... Something I wasn't aware of when posing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft lets you set the default location of documents:

Preferences -> File Location

Select which you want to change and point it to the right folder

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't address my desire to have the file save location adapt to the original files location or the previous save location